# How does the pipeline input step plugin for Jenkins work with SAML/AD Groups?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a declarative pipeline project and would like to employ a gating mechanism that only allows users that are present in certain AD groups to 'promote' the build. In order to do this, I make use of the [input step plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#code-input-code-wait-for-interactive-input).

I started off by using the following:

`input(message: 'Do you want to deploy to the Development Environment?)'`

This works well, then I make use of the `submitter` parameter and provide my email

`input(message: 'Do you want to deploy to the Development Environment?', submitter: "Calvin@xyz.com")`

This allows only me to allow build through. Now I would like to do this based off users in AD Groups. We use the [SAML plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SAML+Plugin) to integrate with Jenkins and it appears that our groups end up looking like so:

`CN=OS-AWS-XYZAdministrator,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=The XYZ Group Object,DC=XYZCORP,DC=local`

We make use of the Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy plugin and one of the 'users/groups' is using the above group to give access to the Jenkins UI along with Build Now privileges which we confirmed works.

When trying to do

`input(message: 'Do you want to deploy to the Development Environment?', submitter: "CN=OS-AWS-XYZAdministrator,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=The XYZ Group Object,DC=XYZCORP,DC=local")`

When any user from that AD group clicks Proceed, they get an error saying:

`You need to be CN=OS-AWS-XYZAdministrator,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=The XYZ Group Object,DC=XYZCORP,DC=local to submit this`

I have also tried `CN=OS-AWS-XYZAdministrator` and `OS-AWS-XYZAdministrator` with no luck. I even tried

`input(message: 'Do you want to deploy to the Development Environment?', submitter: '"CN=OS-AWS-XYZAdministrator,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=The XYZ Group Object,DC=XYZCORP,DC=local"')`

but that did not work

Does `input` actually work with AD Groups? Are the spaces in some of the groups throwing it off?

Thanks
Cal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `CN=OS-AWS-XYZAdministrator,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=The XYZ Group Object,DC=XYZCORP,DC=local` is considered to be an invalid format. You cannot have commas or spaces in your AD group. We had to tweak the LDAP query so we only get `AWS-XYZAdministrator` as the ADGroup according to Jenkins. This fixed it